# How to access instance method from inside of a list?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, casting

So, I'm trying to group sort a list by a particular method of an class. My code currently stores "meals" with Hive by this class format:

https://pub.dev/packages/hive

```dart
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'meal.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1, adapterName: "MealAdapter")
class MealModel{
  @HiveField(0)
  int id;
  @HiveField(1)
  String mealName;
  @HiveField(2)
  int calories;
  @HiveField(3)
  int carbohydrates;
  @HiveField(4)
  int protein;
  @HiveField(5)
  int fats;
  @HiveField(6)
  String day;

  MealModel(this.id, this.mealName, this.calories, this.day, [this.carbohydrates, this.protein, this.fats]);
}
```

The problem is when I have no idea I would pass values to each of the parameters for a GroupedListView (https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list) to display the stored meals:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:jaetrack/colors.dart';
import 'package:jaetrack/dbmodel/meal.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:grouped_list/grouped_list.dart';

class Meals extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MealsState();
  }
}

class MealsState extends State<Meals> {
  Box<MealModel> mealBox = Hive.box<MealModel>('meals');
  MealModel previousMeal;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: mainPurp,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: Hive.box<MealModel>('meals').listenable(),
                builder: (context, Box<MealModel> box, _) {
                  final mealList = box.values.toList().cast<MealModel>();
                  print(mealList);
                  return GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
                    elements: mealList,
                    groupBy: (meal) => meal, // no idea how to sort by calories, name etc. of my MealModel class,
                    groupSeparatorBuilder: (String groupByValue) =>
                        Text(groupByValue), // date value
                    itemBuilder: (context, dynamic element) =>
                        Text(element['name']), // this is where I would put the meal names/calories etc.
                    itemComparator: (item1, item2) =>
                        item1['name'].compareTo(item2['name']), // sort by date is what I'm looking for but again I don't know how to access
                    useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
                    floatingHeader: true,
                    order: GroupedListOrder.ASC,
                  );
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So if I still don't make sense, I cast the values of my hive box of meals as instances of the MealModel above. So the list would be like [Instance of MealModel, Instance of MealModel, ...] I just need to know how to access the values inside of the instance of the MealModel to pass to the GroupedList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`package:grouped_list` library are using `dynamic` in all of their examples to simplify usage for people who don't get generics. but it's misleading in your case, you're losing the strong typing.

cast to

```
return GroupedListView<MealModel, String>(
```

instead of

```
return GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
```

then all of your `element`, `meal` and `item2` vars will be of `MealModel` and you can do `element.mealName`, and `meal.calories` to group by calories

for the sorting question, simply sort `mealList` before passing it to the `GroupedListView`

Comment: I figured it out literally five minutes after I posted my question haha, but thank you for your help! Hopefully this is useful for someone else who has a similar issue.